# Class not found in Spring when using Java modules and jlink

Tags: java, spring, java-module, jlink, moditect

I'm adding module definitions to Spring Boot to be able to jlink my project. One of the errors I encountered is:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: org.springframework.beans.factory.aspectj.AnnotationBeanConfigurerAspect not found.
Could not configure Spring Data JPA auditing-feature because spring-aspects.jar is not on the classpath!
If you want to use auditing please add spring-aspects.jar to the classpath.
        at spring.data.jpa@2.0.8.RELEASE/org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.JpaAuditingRegistrar.registerBeanConfigurerAspectIfNecessary(JpaAuditingRegistrar.java:124)
```

The code throwing this exception look like this:

```
    if (!ClassUtils.isPresent(BEAN_CONFIGURER_ASPECT_CLASS_NAME, getClass().getClassLoader())) {
        throw new BeanDefinitionStoreException(BEAN_CONFIGURER_ASPECT_CLASS_NAME + " not found. \n"
                + "Could not configure Spring Data JPA auditing-feature because"
                + " spring-aspects.jar is not on the classpath!\n"
                + "If you want to use auditing please add spring-aspects.jar to the classpath.");
    }
```

and it's here:

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/config/JpaAuditingRegistrar.java#L123-L128

The definition of `isPresent` is here https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/util/ClassUtils.java#L329

Why isn't it finding the class? Any way to debug it to see why it's failing?

I defined the `spring.data.jpa` module as this:

```
module spring.data.jpa {
    opens org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config to spring.core;
    requires spring.aspects;
    requires spring.beans;
    requires spring.core;
    requires spring.data.commons;
}
```

so it is requiring `spring.aspects` and I defined that one this way (for now at least):

```
module spring.aspects {
    exports org.springframework.beans.factory.aspectj;
    opens org.springframework.beans.factory.aspectj;
}
```

I'm using ModiTect to add the module definitions and so far everything seemed to be working, but for this particular class, I'm not sure what's missing. My complete ModiTect config looks like this:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.moditect</groupId>
    <artifactId>moditect-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>add-module-info-to-dependencies</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>add-module-info</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/modules</outputDirectory>
                <overwriteExistingFiles>true</overwriteExistingFiles>
                <modules>
                    <!-- Direct dependencies -->
                    <module>
                        <artifact>
                            <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
                            <artifactId>bcprov-jdk15on</artifactId>
                        </artifact>
                        <moduleInfoSource>
                            module bcprov.jdk15on {
                            }
                        </moduleInfoSource>
                    </module> <!-- bcprov.jdk15on -->
                    <module>
                        <artifact>
                            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
                        </artifact>
                        <moduleInfoSource>
                            module com.fasterxml.jackson.core {
                            }
                        </moduleInfoSource>
                    </module> <!-- com.fasterxml.jackson.core -->
                    <module>
                        <artifact>
                            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
                        </artifact>
                        <moduleInfoSource>
                            module com.fasterxml.jackson.databind {
                            }
                        </moduleInfoSource>
                    </module> <!-- com.fasterxml.jackson.databind -->
                    <module>
                        <artifact>
                            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
                        </artifact>
                        <moduleInfoSource>
                            module hibernate.core {
                            }
                        </moduleInfoSource>
                    </module> <!-- hibernate.core -->
                    <module>
                        <artifact>
                            <groupId>io.sentry</groupId>
                            <artifactId>sentry</artifactId>
                        </artifact>
                        <moduleInfoSource>
                            module io.sentry {
                            }
                        </moduleInfoSource>
                    </module> <!-- io.sentry -->
                    <module>
                        <artifact>
                            <groupId>io.sentry</groupId>
                            <artifactId>sentry-spring</artifactId>
                        </artifact>
                        <moduleInfoSource>
                            module io.sentry.spring {
                            }
                        </moduleInfoSource>
                    </module> <!-- io.sentry.spring -->
                    <module>
                        <artifact>
                            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
                            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
                        </artifact>
                        <moduleInfoSource>
                            module java.persistence {
                            }
                        </moduleInfoSource>
                    </module> <!-- java.persistence -->
                    <module>
                        <artifact>
                            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
                            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
                        </artifact>
                        <moduleInfoSource>
                            module java.validation {
                            }
                        </moduleInfoSource>
                    </module> <!-- java.validation -->
                    <module>
                        <artifact>
                            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
                            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
                        </artifact>
                        <moduleInfoSource>
                            module javax.inject {
                            }
                        </moduleInfoSource>
                    </module> <!-- javax.inject -->
                    <module>
                        <artifact>
                            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
                            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
                        </artifact>
                        <moduleInfoSource>
                            module org.apache.commons.lang3 {
                            }
                        </moduleInfoSource>
                    </module> <!-- org.apache.commons.lang3 -->
                    <module>
                        <artifact>
                            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                        </artifact>
                        <moduleInfoSource>
                            module slf4j.api {
                            exports org.slf4j;
                            exports org.slf4j.spi;
                            }
                        </moduleInfoSource>
                    </module> <!-- slf4j.api -->
                    <module>
                        <artifact>
                            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
                        </artifact>
                        <moduleInfoSource>
                            module spring.beans {
                            exports org.springframework.beans;
                            exports org.springframework.beans.factory;
                            exports org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation;
                            exports org.springframework.beans.factory.config;
                            exports org.springframework.beans.factory.support;
                            exports org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing;
                            exports org.springframework.beans.factory.xml;
                            exports org.springframework.beans.propertyeditors;
                            exports org.springframework.beans.support;
                            requires java.desktop;
                            requires spring.core;
                            requires spring.jcl;
                            }
                        </moduleInfoSource>
                    </module> <!-- spring.beans -->
                    <module>
                        <artifact>
                            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
                        </artifact>
                        <moduleInfoSource>
                            module spring.core {
                            exports org.springframework.asm;
                            exports org.springframework.core;
                            exports org.springframework.core.annotation;
                            exports org.springframework.core.convert;
                            exports org.springframework.core.convert.converter;
                            exports org.springframework.core.convert.support;
                            exports org.springframework.core.env;
                            exports org.springframework.core.io;
                            exports org.springframework.core.io.support;
                            exports org.springframework.core.type;
                            exports org.springframework.core.type.filter;
                            exports org.springframework.core.type.classreading;
                            exports org.springframework.util;
                            exports org.springframework.util.xml;
                            requires java.desktop;
                            requires java.xml;
                            requires spring.jcl;
                            }
                        </moduleInfoSource>
                    </module> <!-- spring.core -->
                    <module>
                        <artifact>
                            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
                        </artifact>
                        <moduleInfoSource>
                            module spring.web {
                            }
                        </moduleInfoSource>
                    </module> <!-- spring.web -->
                    <module>
                        <artifact>
                            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                            <artifactId>spring-boot</artifactId>
                        </artifact>
                        <moduleInfoSource>
                            module spring.boot {
                            exports org.springframework.boot;
                            exports org.springframework.boot.builder;
                            exports org.springframework.boot.cloud;
                            exports org.springframework.boot.context;
                            exports org.springframework.boot.context.annotation;
                            exports org.springframework.boot.context.config;
                            exports org.springframework.boot.context.event;
                            exports org.springframework.boot.context.logging;
                            exports org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind;
                            exports org.springframework.boot.env;
                            exports org.springframework.boot.jdbc;
                            exports org.springframework.boot.liquibase;
                            exports org.springframework.boot.type.classreading;
                            exports org.springframework.boot.web.context;
                            exports org.springframework.boot.web.reactive.context;
                            opens org.springframework.boot to spring.core;
                            opens org.springframework.boot.diagnostics to spring.core;
                            opens org.springframework.boot.context.properties to spring.beans, spring.core;
                            opens org.springframework.boot.logging.java;
                            requires java.logging;
                            requires spring.beans;
                            requires spring.context;
                            requires spring.core;
                            requires spring.jcl;
                            requires spring.jdbc;
                            }
                        </moduleInfoSource>
                    </module> <!-- spring.boot -->
                    <module>
                        <artifact>
                            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                            <artifactId>spring-boot-autoconfigure</artifactId>
                        </artifact>
                        <moduleInfoSource>
                            module spring.boot.autoconfigure {
                            exports org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure;
                            exports org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.logging;
                            opens org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure to spring.core;
                            opens org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.cache to spring.core;
                            opens org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition to spring.core;
                            opens org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.context to spring.core;
                            opens org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc to spring.core;
                            requires spring.beans;
                            requires spring.context;
                            requires spring.core;
                            requires spring.boot;
                            requires spring.jcl;
                            }
                        </moduleInfoSource>
                    </module> <!-- spring.boot.autoconfigure -->
                    <module>
                        <artifact>
                            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
                        </artifact>
                        <moduleInfoSource>
                            module spring.context {
                            exports org.springframework.context;
                            exports org.springframework.context.annotation;
                            exports org.springframework.context.event;
                            exports org.springframework.context.support;
                            exports org.springframework.format;
                            exports org.springframework.format.support;
                            exports org.springframework.stereotype;
                            requires java.desktop;
                            requires spring.aop;
                            requires spring.beans;
                            requires spring.core;
                            requires spring.expression;
                            requires spring.jcl;
                            }
                        </moduleInfoSource>
                    </module> <!-- spring.context -->
                    <module>
                        <artifact>
                            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
                            <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>
                        </artifact>
                        <moduleInfoSource>
                            module spring.data.commons {
                            exports org.springframework.data.auditing.config;
                            requires spring.context;
                            }
                        </moduleInfoSource>
                    </module> <!-- spring.data.commons -->
                    <module>
                        <artifact>
                            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
                            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
                        </artifact>
                        <moduleInfoSource>
                            module spring.data.jpa {
                            opens org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config to spring.core;
                            requires spring.aspects;
                            requires spring.beans;
                            requires spring.core;
                            requires spring.data.commons;
                            }
                        </moduleInfoSource>
                    </module> <!-- spring.data.jpa -->
                    <module>
                        <artifact>
                            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
                        </artifact>
                        <moduleInfoSource>
                            module spring.jdbc {
                            exports org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.embedded;
                            }
                        </moduleInfoSource>
                    </module> <!-- spring.jdbc -->
                    <module>
                        <artifact>
                            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
                            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
                        </artifact>
                        <moduleInfoSource>
                            module spring.security.config {
                            }
                        </moduleInfoSource>
                    </module> <!-- spring.security.config -->
                    <module>
                        <artifact>
                            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
                            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
                        </artifact>
                        <moduleInfoSource>
                            module spring.security.core {
                            }
                        </moduleInfoSource>
                    </module> <!-- spring.security.core -->
                    <module>
                        <artifact>
                            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
                        </artifact>
                        <moduleInfoSource>
                            module spring.tx {
                            exports org.springframework.transaction.annotation;
                            requires spring.context;
                            requires spring.core;
                            }
                        </moduleInfoSource>
                    </module> <!-- spring.tx -->
                    <module>
                        <artifact>
                            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
                        </artifact>
                        <moduleInfoSource>
                            module spring.webmvc {
                            }
                        </moduleInfoSource>
                    </module> <!-- spring.webmvc -->
                    <module>
                        <artifact>
                            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
                            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-core</artifactId>
                        </artifact>
                        <moduleInfoSource>
                            module tomcat.embed.core {
                            }
                        </moduleInfoSource>
                    </module> <!-- tomcat.embed.core -->
                    <!-- Dependencies of dependencies -->
                    <module>
                        <artifact>
                            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
                        </artifact>
                        <moduleInfoSource>
                            module jackson.annotations {
                            }
                        </moduleInfoSource>
                    </module> <!-- jackson.annotations -->
                    <module>
                        <artifact>
                            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
                        </artifact>
                        <moduleInfoSource>
                            module spring.aop {
                            exports org.springframework.aop.framework;
                            exports org.springframework.aop.support;
                            requires spring.core;
                            }
                        </moduleInfoSource>
                    </module> <!-- spring.aop -->
                    <module>
                        <artifact>
                            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                            <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
                        </artifact>
                        <moduleInfoSource>
                            module spring.aspects {
                            exports org.springframework.beans.factory.aspectj;
                            opens org.springframework.beans.factory.aspectj;
                            }
                        </moduleInfoSource>
                    </module> <!-- spring.aspects -->
                    <module>
                        <artifact>
                            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                            <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
                        </artifact>
                        <moduleInfoSource>
                            module spring.expression {
                            exports org.springframework.expression;
                            exports org.springframework.expression.spel;
                            exports org.springframework.expression.spel.standard;
                            exports org.springframework.expression.spel.support;
                            requires spring.core;
                            }
                        </moduleInfoSource>
                    </module> <!-- spring.expression -->
                    <module>
                        <artifact>
                            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                            <artifactId>spring-jcl</artifactId>
                        </artifact>
                        <moduleInfoSource>
                            module spring.jcl {
                            exports org.apache.commons.logging;
                            requires slf4j.api;
                            }
                        </moduleInfoSource>
                    </module> <!-- spring.jcl -->
                </modules>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>create-runtime-image</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>create-runtime-image</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <modulePath>
                    <path>${project.build.directory}/classes</path>
                    <path>${project.build.directory}/modules</path>
                    <path>c:\Users\pupeno\.m2\repository\tech\flexpoint\dashmancommon\1.0.0-beta.11</path>
                </modulePath>
                <modules>
                    <module>tech.flexpoint.dashmanserver</module>
                </modules>
                <launcher>
                    <name>dashmanserver</name>
                    <module>
                        tech.flexpoint.dashmanserver/tech.flexpoint.dashmanserver.DashmanServerApplication
                    </module>
                </launcher>
                <outputDirectory>
                    ${project.build.directory}/jlink-image
                </outputDirectory>
                <ignoreSigningInformation>true</ignoreSigningInformation>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

I suspect this might be a bug, so, I reported it here: https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-17018

Comment: Were you able to get it working? I'm struggling with a similar problem, `@ComponentScan` is not detecting any classes is my `jlink`'ed Spring app: https://stackoverflow.com/q/57183100/5801146