# @ComponentScan does not detect beans in a jlink'ed Java runtime image

Tags: java, spring, maven, jlink, moditect

I'm using JavaFX on Java 11 to create a desktop app. The app is bundled into a custom runtime image with all its modules and their dependencies using `jlink`. For dependency injection, the app relies on the Spring Framework.

I'm aware that Spring modules currently do not include a `module-info.class`, instead they are shipped as "automatic modules". Since automatic modules cannot be bundled with `jlink`, I manually added `module-info.class` to each Spring dependency JAR using the Moditect Maven Plugin. Here are the respective parts of `pom.xml`:

```
    ...
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${dependency.spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.moditect</groupId>
                <artifactId>moditect-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0.Beta2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>add-module-infos</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>add-module-info</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/dependencies</outputDirectory>
                            <modules>
                                <module>
                                    <artifact>
                                        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                                        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
                                    </artifact>
                                    <moduleInfoSource>
                                        module spring.context {
                                        opens org.springframework.context.support to spring.core;
                                        requires java.naming;
                                        exports org.springframework.validation.annotation;
                                        exports org.springframework.ui.context.support;
                                        exports org.springframework.validation;
                                        exports org.springframework.jndi;
                                        exports org.springframework.context.annotation;
                                        exports org.springframework.context.event;
                                        exports org.springframework.context.support;
                                        exports org.springframework.context;
                                        exports org.springframework.format.support;
                                        exports org.springframework.format;
                                        exports org.springframework.jmx.export.naming;
                                        exports org.springframework.stereotype;
                                        exports org.springframework.ui.context;
                                        opens org.springframework.context.annotation to spring.core, spring.beans, com.my.app;
                                        opens org.springframework.instrument.classloading to spring.data.jpa;
                                        requires java.desktop;
                                        requires spring.aop;
                                        requires spring.beans;
                                        requires spring.core;
                                        requires spring.expression;
                                        requires spring.jcl;
                                        //requires java.annotation;
                                        }
                                    </moduleInfoSource>
                                </module>
                                <module>
                                    <artifact>
                                        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                                        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
                                    </artifact>
                                    <moduleInfoSource>
                                        module spring.aop {
                                        exports org.springframework.aop.config;
                                        exports org.springframework.aop.framework;
                                        exports org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy;
                                        exports org.springframework.aop.support;
                                        exports org.springframework.aop.aspectj.annotation;
                                        opens org.aopalliance.intercept to spring.tx;
                                        requires spring.beans;
                                        requires spring.core;
                                        requires spring.jcl;
                                        //requires aspectjrt;
                                        exports org.springframework.aop.scope;
                                        }
                                    </moduleInfoSource>
                                </module>
                                <module>
                                    <artifact>
                                        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                                        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
                                    </artifact>
                                    <moduleInfoSource>
                                        module spring.beans {
                                        exports org.springframework.beans.factory.wiring;
                                        exports org.springframework.beans;
                                        exports org.springframework.beans.factory;
                                        exports org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation;
                                        exports org.springframework.beans.factory.config;
                                        exports org.springframework.beans.factory.support;
                                        exports org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing;
                                        exports org.springframework.beans.factory.xml;
                                        exports org.springframework.beans.propertyeditors;
                                        exports org.springframework.beans.support;
                                        requires java.management.rmi;
                                        requires java.desktop;
                                        requires spring.core;
                                        requires spring.jcl;
                                        }
                                    </moduleInfoSource>
                                </module>
                                <module>
                                    <artifact>
                                        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                                        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
                                    </artifact>
                                    <moduleInfoSource>
                                        module spring.core {
                                        exports org.springframework.cglib.reflect;
                                        exports org.springframework.util.comparator;
                                        exports org.springframework.asm;
                                        exports org.springframework.cglib.core;
                                        exports org.springframework.cglib.proxy;
                                        exports org.springframework.cglib.transform;
                                        exports org.springframework.core;
                                        exports org.springframework.core.annotation;
                                        exports org.springframework.core.convert;
                                        exports org.springframework.core.convert.converter;
                                        exports org.springframework.core.convert.support;
                                        exports org.springframework.core.env;
                                        exports org.springframework.core.io;
                                        exports org.springframework.core.io.support;
                                        exports org.springframework.core.type;
                                        exports org.springframework.core.type.filter;
                                        exports org.springframework.core.type.classreading;
                                        exports org.springframework.objenesis;
                                        exports org.springframework.util;
                                        exports org.springframework.util.xml;
                                        //requires aspectjrt;
                                        //requires javassist;
                                        requires jdk.jconsole;
                                        requires java.desktop;
                                        requires java.management;
                                        requires java.xml;
                                        requires spring.jcl;
                                        }
                                    </moduleInfoSource>
                                </module>
                                <module>
                                    <artifact>
                                        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                                        <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
                                    </artifact>
                                    <moduleInfoSource>
                                        module spring.expression {
                                        exports org.springframework.expression;
                                        exports org.springframework.expression.spel;
                                        exports org.springframework.expression.spel.standard;
                                        exports org.springframework.expression.spel.support;
                                        requires spring.core;
                                        }
                                    </moduleInfoSource>
                                </module>
                                <module>
                                    <artifact>
                                        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                                        <artifactId>spring-jcl</artifactId>
                                    </artifact>
                                    <moduleInfoSource>
                                        module spring.jcl {
                                        requires java.logging;
                                        exports org.apache.commons.logging;
                                        }
                                    </moduleInfoSource>
                                </module>
                            </modules>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    ...
```

With the above-mentioned module definitions, `jlink` succeeds without problems and my app is bundled into a custom runtime image that contains all its dependencies.

However, if I run the app using the bundled JRE, problems arise:

```sh
java -m com.my.app/com.my.app.Main
```

causes an `IllegalAccessException`:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: module spring.core does not read module com.my.app
    at java.base/java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles.privateLookupIn(MethodHandles.java:197)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at spring.core@5.1.8.RELEASE/org.springframework.cglib.core.ReflectUtils.defineClass(ReflectUtils.java:500)
    ... 25 more
```

According to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53535527/5801146), the error can be fixed using `--add-reads`:

```sh
java --add-reads spring.core=com.my.app -m com.my.app/com.my.app.Main
```

Instead, a different kind of `IllegalAccessException` is thrown:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class com.my.app.AppConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$e9ee1f7f (in module com.my.app) cannot access class org.springframework.cglib.core.ReflectUtils (in module spring.core) because module com.my.app does not read module spring.core
    at com.my.app/com.my.app.AppConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$e9ee1f7f.CGLIB$STATICHOOK1(<generated>)
    at com.my.app/com.my.app.AppConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$e9ee1f7f.<clinit>(<generated>)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:398)
    at spring.core@5.1.8.RELEASE/org.springframework.cglib.core.ReflectUtils.defineClass(ReflectUtils.java:563)
    at spring.core@5.1.8.RELEASE/org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.generate(AbstractClassGenerator.java:363)
    at spring.core@5.1.8.RELEASE/org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.generate(Enhancer.java:582)
    at spring.core@5.1.8.RELEASE/org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData$3.apply(AbstractClassGenerator.java:110)
    at spring.core@5.1.8.RELEASE/org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData$3.apply(AbstractClassGenerator.java:108)
    at spring.core@5.1.8.RELEASE/org.springframework.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache$2.call(LoadingCache.java:54)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at spring.core@5.1.8.RELEASE/org.springframework.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache.createEntry(LoadingCache.java:61)
    ... 18 more
```

As suggested by the error message, I then added another `--add-reads` parameter:

```
java --add-reads spring.core=com.my.app --add-reads com.my.app=spring.core -m com.my.app/com.my.app.Main
```

Now the app starts and reads its `AppConfig.class`, which is annotated with `@ComponentScan`:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
class AppConfig {
}
```

However, Spring does not detect a single class of the project that is annotated with a stereotype (`@Component`, `@Service`), as the output of `Main.java` indicates:

```
public class Main extends Application {

    private ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void init() {
        applicationContext = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(AppConfig.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage mainWindow) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("Printing beans: " + applicationContext.getBeanDefinitionNames().length);
        for (String beanDefinitionName : applicationContext.getBeanDefinitionNames()) {
            System.out.println(beanDefinitionName);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() {
        applicationContext.stop();
    }
}
```

```
Printing beans: 5
org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor
org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor
org.springframework.context.event.internalEventListenerProcessor
org.springframework.context.event.internalEventListenerFactory
appConfig
```

Why does `@ComponentScan` miss all my annotated classes? `AppConfig.java` is in the root package of my app and all the classes reside in subpackages, therefore Spring should be able to detect them based on the given configuration.

For completeness, here's the `module-info.java` of my app:

```
module com.my.app {
    requires java.logging;
    requires transitive javafx.graphics;
    requires transitive javafx.controls;
    requires transitive javafx.fxml;
    requires spring.context;
    requires spring.beans;
    requires java.sql;

    exports com.my.app;
    exports com.my.app.controllers;
    exports com.my.app.controllers.modals;
    exports com.my.app.models;
    exports com.my.app.exceptions;
    exports com.my.app.services;
    exports com.my.app.services.impl;

    opens com.my.app to spring.aop, spring.beans, spring.context, spring.core, spring.expression, spring.jcl;
    opens com.my.app.controllers to spring.aop, spring.beans, spring.context, spring.core, spring.expression, spring.jcl;
    opens com.my.app.controllers.modals to spring.aop, spring.beans, spring.context, spring.core, spring.expression, spring.jcl;
    opens com.my.app.services to spring.aop, spring.beans, spring.context, spring.core, spring.expression, spring.jcl;
    opens com.my.app.services.impl to spring.aop, spring.beans, spring.context, spring.core, spring.expression, spring.jcl;
}
```